# Why Chrome mobile emulation is moving element when width shrinks?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My block element is moving with a mind of it's own.

Create a new `index.html` page with this content. Shrink the page width and notice it behaves as expected. Turn on the mobile device "responsive" emulation, and shrink the width. Why is the `<div>` moving?

The `#outer` element is height and width 100%, position absolute

`#inner` element has bottom:0, which should always anchor to the bottom of the viewport

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

#outer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='outer'>
    <div id='inner'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in Device Mode. I reported an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=695144).

Reproduce:

1. Click **Run code snippet**.
2. Click **Full page**.
3. Reduce the width of your browser. The green bar at the bottom stays the same height.
4. Open Device Mode in Responsive Mode.
5. Use Device Mode's handles to reduce the viewport's size. The height of the green bar changes.

```css
#outer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, yea it seems like a bug

Comment: They answered with wontfix because of lacking viewport meta. I still experience the issue even with viewport set to `device-width`. The strange things happen when I decrease width below 240px (if there is no vieport meta, it goes below the screen very quickly, if viewport is set in moves up). **Neither of issues is present in Firefox dev. tools**.